# Instantiate a serviceprovider for UnitTest project

Tags: asp.net-core, service-provider

So here is a little bit of context :

I have an ASP.NET core Project with everything setted up. I have different services which I need to test.
I created a UnitTest Project for that purpose.

My problem is that when I try to test a google drive upload service (which is in need of a service provider(IServiceProvider)), but I couldn t find any way to instantiate a service provider, normally It is intanciated in the startup by ASP.Net Core itself, but like I said, for testing purposes, I need it to be fully instanciated from scratch in my UnitTest Project.

Here is my current setup for the UnitTest Project:

```
  IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()


.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
 .Build();


 var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
 Startup s = new Startup(configuration);
 s.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
 
 /*serviceCollection.AddScoped<GoogleService>();
 //serviceCollection.AddSingleton(_appContext);
 serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Service.Domains.ApplicationDomain.Bll.Models.ApplicationCache>();
 serviceCollection.AddScoped<Service.Services.AuditService>();
 serviceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor();*/


 IServiceProvider provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

 //services.AddScoped<Service.Services.AuditService>();
 _service = new AuditService(GetDatabaseContext(), configuration, provider);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the fix was simple :

We can reuse the HostBuilder In the Program class :

```cs
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.Build();


var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
Startup s = new Startup(configuration);
s.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
var hostBuilder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[] { }).Build().Services;

//services.AddScoped<Service.Services.AuditService>();
_auditService = new AuditService(GetDatabaseContext(), configuration, hostBuilder.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>());
```